# Company proxy: Browser in emulator can call url `https://google.com`, but Flutter app doesn't

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, proxy, android-emulator

I'm facing an issue relates to company proxy. I want to call url `https://google.com`, here are 3 situations:

- In Windows Google Chrome, it can access `google.com`.
- In emulator's browswer, it can also access `google.com`.
- In my Flutter app, I use `dio.get(https://google.com)` but it is blocked by something. The response is **"connection timeout"**. I did try to use `http` package instead of `dio`, but no result.

I still call `flutter pub get`, and `flutter doctor` give no error. I tried with Flutter 3.3.10, 3.7.12 & 3.10.6.

I try many solutions, include:

- Add proxy to Visual Studio Code.
- Add proxy to Android Sudio.
- Add proxy to emulator Extended Controls (3 dots symbols at side bar)
- Add proxy to emulator's wifi settings.
- Add `http_proxy`, `https_proxy` in Windows enviroment variables.

But none of them works. If you meet the same issue, I super super **thank you**. Too tired with corporation proxy, they block everything.